# Background properties do not work with tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

I recently decided to learn more about web development and a friend introduced me to the tailwind. I had some initial problems with setting it up but I finally managed to do it yesterday. I tried a few classes to see if it works and it was fine. Then I closed vs code and everything else and wanted to work on it more today but nothing changed when I add classes except the ones I already added. For example, I used bg-cyan-500 just for the fun of it. I can still use it to manipulate the document but if I go with bg-cyan-400 doesn't work. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please tell us what kind of tech stack you are using and how you setup tailwind?

Comment: Do you compile styles again with some watch command and add new class or just added new class in HTML without running any command?

Comment: Thank you very much, guys. I resolved the issue. Apparently, I didn't understand how tailwind exactly works. The problem is, I didn't run the --watch command when I started working on my project again, thus, tailwind didn't pick up the changes and added the new styles to my style sheet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, guys. I resolved the issue. Apparently, I didn't understand how tailwind exactly works. The problem is that I didn't run the --watch command when I started working on my project again, thus, tailwind didn't pick up the changes and added the new styles to my style sheet.

So I just used "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch" command to the terminal and it worked again. I can't believe I missed something so fundamental.